# Does the Weyl tensor need to be continuous across a membrane with stress-energy that separates two different space-times?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, boundary-conditions

Imagine that I have two $N$+1 dimensional space-times separated by a co-dimension 1 boundary. At the boundary there is a membrane containing stress-energy. The stress-energy tensor of that membrane has delta-function support in the direction of a normal vector field. The N+1 dimensional space-times also have stress-energy tensors.

What I would like to do is specify a co-dimension 1 hypersurface in each of the two space-times, and identify those hypersuraces. What I understand is that I need the induced metric on the hypersurfaces to match, and I need to satisfy the Israel junction conditions (ie: difference in extrinsic curvature of the two boundary hypersurfaces to match the stress-energy on the membrane. Once this is done, is the surgery complete? Or must I match other quantities, such as the Weyl tensor?

Question: Does the Weyl tensor need to be continuous across a membrane with stress-energy that separates two different space-times?

I have not found a definite answer to this question in the literature - references would be appreciated. Some resources seem to suggest that the Weyl tensor on one side of the boundary must match the Weyl tensor on the other side of the boundary. However, these seem to be working with situations in which there is no stress-energy on the boundary. On the other hand, it seems that in the Randall-Sundrum brane-cosmology scenario, $Z/2Z$ (reflection) symmetry is imposed across a membrane that contains stress-energy (with delta-function support), and the bulk space-times on either side also contain stress-energy. Authors of some papers on this matter speak of different values of the Weyl tensor on either side of the membrane.

My intuition is this - and I easily could be wrong:
If there is no delta-function-supported stress-energy on the membrane, then perhaps the Weyl tensor should be continuous across that boundary. However, when the membrane does contain delta-function-supported stress-energy, and the induced metric on either side of boundary is the same, and the Israel junction conditions are satisfied, it seems reasonable that the Weyl tensor might be discontinuous across the boundary - at least I don't see any reason it needs to be continuous.

So, if the induced metric on the membrane from either side matches, and the Israel junction conditions (jump in extrinsic curvature vs stress-energy on the membrane) are satisfied, am I finished, and my surgery is complete? Or must further matching of other quantities be done?

If more matching must be done, please recommend a resource that will explain the matter.